# Activate Device Administrator via ADB

Tags: adb, device-administrator

Is it possible to activate Device Administrator via ADB command instead of tapping

***"Setting -> Security -> Device Administrators --> Select App --> Activate"***

on handheld?

If it's possible, how?

Comment: You should consider accepting [вʀaᴎᴅᴏƞ вєнᴎєƞ's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/202285/94968) as it works perfectly!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tested and working on Android 7.0 without root:

```
adb shell
dpm set-active-admin --user current com.company.foo.bar.package/.the.Admin.Reciever
```

To find the admin receiver of an installed package, use the following to adb shell command and review the output:

```
adb shell
pm dump com.company.foo.bar.package | grep ' filter' | cut -d ' ' -f 12 | sort | uniq
```

To give a real world example, here is the command used to activate IBM's Maas360 Android client as a device admin:

```
adb shell
pm dump com.fiberlink.maas360.android.control | grep ' filter' | cut -d ' ' -f 12 | sort | uniq

Output:
…
com.fiberlink.maas360.android.control/.receivers.GoogleCampaignReceiver
com.fiberlink.maas360.android.control/.receivers.LocalEventReceiver
com.fiberlink.maas360.android.control/.receivers.Maas360DeviceAdminReceiver  <-- This is the one I want
com.fiberlink.maas360.android.control/.receivers.Maas360SecondaryDeviceAdminReceiver
…


Set Device Admin:    
dpm set-active-admin --user current com.fiberlink.maas360.android.control/.receivers.Maas360DeviceAdminReceiver
```

Comment: IT WORKS! This must be the accepted answer! I have one question, is it possible to add an extra to that command? I need to request the Samsung Knox license activation right after the administrator activation and I would like to pass the license's key as an extra (so I do not have to store it in my code or on my device)

Comment: Note that `dpm set-active-admin` is not available on Android 5, but you can get a similar effect using `dpm set-device-owner`

Comment: This still works in Android 9.

Comment: The command to get the Receiver does NOT work in here. I tried via Termux and via Terminal Emulator. The command returns nothing. If I use SU, then I get some random numbers. Already checked if the package name is right. Android 9

Comment: **Update to my previous comment:** for those who the command to get the Admin Receiver of an app don't work, one can find it, if the app is ALREADY an admin, in here: */data/system/device_policies.xml*

Answer (score 7):

It's not possible. [The settings code](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/src/com/android/settings/DeviceAdminAdd.java) is specifically written to prevent this. The closest  you can come is to bring up the **Device Administration Settings** page in the **Settings** app. You can do this with:

```
adb shell am start -S "com.android.settings/.Settings\$DeviceAdminSettingsActivity"
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, 
Little correction : it should be

`adb shell am start -S "com.android.settings/.Settings\$DeviceAdminSettingsActivity"`

Without single quote

Comment: In most shells, that command will just start **Settings**, not the **Device administration settings** page. Here's [Izzy's explanation of why](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/45070/starting-an-activity-listed-under-settings-from-terminal-or-adb-shell/45074#45074).

Comment: What about disabling? is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, provided that you've root access. You would have to add the app's receiver and the policy flag in the file `/data/system/device_policies.xml`. For example, to enable [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) as Device administrator add the following lines in the said file,

**For Android 5.x:** Remove the last line with `</policies>` if there is already a  Device Administrator enabled in the system. Simply add the lines in the file after the line with string `<policies setup-complete="true">`.

```
<admin name="net.dinglisch.android.taskerm/net.dinglisch.android.taskerm.MyDeviceAdminReceiver">
<policies flags="8" />
</admin>
</policies>
```

**For Android 4.2.1:** Remove the last line with `</policies>` if there is already a  Device Administrator enabled in the system. Simply add the lines in the file after the line with string `<policies>`.

```
<admin name="net.dinglisch.android.taskerm/net.dinglisch.android.taskerm.MyDeviceAdminReceiver">
<policies flags="8" />
</admin>
</policies>
```

Reboot the device for the changes to take effect.

([Busybox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox) required)  You can use `sed` or `echo` or any command that you're comfortable with to write the file with those lines. For any help, see my answer here: [How to enable device administrator for specific apps using Tasker?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/124148)

Answer (score 1):

you can set the Device as owner from Android Studio. First go to the adb location which is at Platform-tools in Android Sdk and then run the adb shell command. I have give the full path and you can adjust at your requirement upon changing adb path and package name

```
C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>adb shell dpm set-device-owner package-name/.MyDeviceAdminReceiver
```

MyDeviceAdminReceiver is the interface.

Comment: Note that once an app is set as *owner* it is very difficult to undo this

Comment: hi @Sam I know but fortunately we can do this through coding to undo the owner

Answer (score -1):

This *is* possible. You can use android's new tool UI-Automator to click and interact with any view or button on the system including hitting "Activate" for device admin. Here's how:

1. Get [UI-Automator](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html) running. (go to "Configure your development environment" and setup a new java project).
2. Write some code to interact with your preferences list and click "Activate". Example:

   UiScrollable settingsItem = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().className("android.widget.ListView"));
   UiObject listButton = settingsItem.getChildByText(new UiSelector().className("android.widget.LinearLayout"), "Enable Device Admin");
   listButton.click();
   (new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Activate"))).clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
   me.celebrateWith(new Beer());
3. Compile it: `ant build`
4. Push the jar file: `adb -d push bin/LookoutTest.jar /data/local/tmp/`
5. Launch your settings activity: `adb shell am start -S "'com.android.settings/.Settings\$DeviceAdminSettingsActivity'"`
6. Run the automation: `adb -d shell uiautomator runtest LookoutTest.jar -c DALaunch`
7. Party.

Comment: Will this work even if the current locale of the device isn't English?