# Unable to activate Tasker as Device Administrator

Tags: tasker, device-administrator

I'm using a rooted Note 2 GT-N7100 running DR.Ketan Custom ROM v14.

After flashing this ROM today, I'm unable to use Tasker as a Device Administrator. The check box does not get checked when I click it in order to Activate Device Administrator permission to Tasker to perform certain tasks.

Kindly help me find a solution – Thankx in advance!

Comment: Do you have any screen dimming/brightness apps installed (Such as [Lux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vito.lux))?

Answer (score 1):

In the file `/data/system/device_policies.xml` remove everything and  add the following lines,

For Lollipop 5.x.x:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<policies setup-complete="true">
<admin name="net.dinglisch.android.taskerm/net.dinglisch.android.taskerm.MyDeviceAdminReceiver">
<policies flags="8" />
</admin>
</policies>
```

For Android 4.2.1:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<policies>
<admin name="net.dinglisch.android.taskerm/net.dinglisch.android.taskerm.MyDeviceAdminReceiver">
<policies flags="8" />
</admin>
</policies>
```

Reboot the device and Tasker would now be found enabled as Device administrator. However, all other apps previously enabled as Device administrator would eventually be found stripped from that privilege. You would have to manually grant them the privilege from **Settings** app.

For any reasoning, see my answer here: [How to enable device administrator for specific apps using Tasker?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/124148)