# How to disable device administrator that stops Settings app?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, device-administrator

I try to disable two apps: Tasker and Applock, from device administrators, but when I tap to uncheck it, the Settings app stops. Other device admins like Cerberus can be enabled/disabled.

I sent an email to Tasker developer but received this answer:

> Have you disabled Tasker and restarted the device ?
>
> In any case, if the Settings app is stopping that's a bug in the
>   Settings app on your device, not in Tasker, I'm sorry to say.  Tasker
>   has no influence on what Settings does when the button is checked or
>   unchecked,  and you're the first person in 6 years to report a crash
>   in Settings from disabling the Device Admin.

**logcat via adb** shows an uncaught exception:

```
12-01 18:46:20.764 22303 22303 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-01 18:46:20.764 22303 22303 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.android.settings, PID: 22303
12-01 18:46:20.764 22303 22303 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.android.settings/com.android.settings.DeviceAdminAdd}: java.lang.SecurityException: net.dinglisch.android.taskerm from uid 10134 not allowed to perform SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
12-01 18:46:20.764 22303 22303 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3124)
12-01 18:46:20.764 22303 22303 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3155)
12-01 18:46:20.764 22303 22303 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2498)
12-01 18:46:20.764 22303 22303 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
12-01 18:46:20.764 22303 22303 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1357)
12-01 18:46:20.764 22303 22303 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-01 18:46:20.764 22303 22303 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
12-01 18:46:20.764 22303 22303 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5459)
12-01 18:46:20.764 22303 22303 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-01 18:46:20.764 22303 22303 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
12-01 18:46:20.764 22303 22303 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
12-01 18:46:20.764 22303 22303 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: net.dinglisch.android.taskerm from uid 10134 not allowed to perform SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
12-01 18:46:20.764 22303 22303 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.AppOpsManager.checkOp(AppOpsManager.java:1521)
12-01 18:46:20.764 22303 22303 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.settings.DeviceAdminAdd.onResume(DeviceAdminAdd.java:384)
12-01 18:46:20.764 22303 22303 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1281)
12-01 18:46:20.764 22303 22303 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6335)
12-01 18:46:20.764 22303 22303 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3113)
12-01 18:46:20.764 22303 22303 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 10 more
12-01 18:46:30.174 23612 23612 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-01 18:46:30.174 23612 23612 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.android.settings, PID: 23612
12-01 18:46:30.174 23612 23612 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.android.settings/com.android.settings.DeviceAdminAdd}: java.lang.SecurityException: com.domobile.applock from uid 10161 not allowed to perform SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
12-01 18:46:30.174 23612 23612 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3124)
12-01 18:46:30.174 23612 23612 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3155)
12-01 18:46:30.174 23612 23612 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2498)
12-01 18:46:30.174 23612 23612 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
12-01 18:46:30.174 23612 23612 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1357)
12-01 18:46:30.174 23612 23612 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-01 18:46:30.174 23612 23612 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
12-01 18:46:30.174 23612 23612 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5459)
12-01 18:46:30.174 23612 23612 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-01 18:46:30.174 23612 23612 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
12-01 18:46:30.174 23612 23612 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
12-01 18:46:30.174 23612 23612 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: com.domobile.applock from uid 10161 not allowed to perform SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
12-01 18:46:30.174 23612 23612 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.AppOpsManager.checkOp(AppOpsManager.java:1521)
12-01 18:46:30.174 23612 23612 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.settings.DeviceAdminAdd.onResume(DeviceAdminAdd.java:384)
12-01 18:46:30.174 23612 23612 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1281)
12-01 18:46:30.174 23612 23612 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6335)
12-01 18:46:30.174 23612 23612 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3113)
12-01 18:46:30.174 23612 23612 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 10 more
```

**Device info**

```
ro.bootimage.build.fingerprint]: [motorola/harpia_retail/harpia:6.0.1/MPI24.241-15.3/3:user/release-keys]
[ro.bootloader]: [0x8104]
[ro.bootmode]: [normal]
[ro.bootreason]: [power_key_press]
[ro.bug2go.magickeys]: [24,26]
[ro.build.characteristics]: [default]
[ro.build.date]: [Sat Jul  9 02:59:12 CDT 2016]
[ro.build.date.utc]: [1468051152]
[ro.build.description]: [harpia-user 6.0.1 MPI24.241-15.3 3 release-keys]
[ro.build.display.id]: [MPI24.241-15.3]
[ro.build.fingerprint]: [motorola/harpia/harpia:6.0.1/MPI24.241-15.3/3:user/release-keys]
[ro.build.flavor]: [harpia-user]
[ro.build.host]: [ilclbld31]
[ro.build.id]: [MPI24.241-15.3]
[ro.build.product]: [harpia]
[ro.build.tags]: [release-keys]
[ro.build.thumbprint]: [6.0.1/MPI24.241-15.3/3:user/release-keys]
[ro.build.type]: [user]
[ro.build.user]: [hudsoncm]
[ro.build.version.all_codenames]: [REL]
[ro.build.version.base_os]: []
[ro.build.version.codename]: [REL]
[ro.build.version.full]: [Blur_Version.24.71.3.harpia.retail.en.US]
[ro.build.version.incremental]: [3]
[ro.build.version.preview_sdk]: [0]
[ro.build.version.qcom]: [AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.1.3_RB1.05.01.00.032.015]
[ro.build.version.release]: [6.0.1]
[ro.build.version.sdk]: [23]
[ro.build.version.security_patch]: [2016-06-01]
```

Is it possible to disable these device admins without resetting the device?

Comment: If you're believing a third party app is causing the crashes then consider switching the Android into safe mode and then attempt to remove the device admin. Otherwise, if your Android is rooted, you can remove the device admin without bothering with app crashes. Let us know the results.

Comment: Safe mode didn't work to disable them :( , I know but I can't root it for warranty reasons

Comment: Related, just the opposite direction: [Unable to activate Tasker as Device Administrator](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/87835/16575)

Answer (score 2):

1. First, give that app *Overlay Permission*

   Go to Phone Settings -> Applications -> Apps that can appear on top (in "..." overflow menu on top) -> Check "Your app to uninstall"
2. Second, disable that app from *Device Administrators* from Phone Settings.
3. Now you can uninstall as regular app

Answer (score 1):

The problem can also be solved like this:

1. Go to Settings -> Apps.
2. Click on menu, then click 'Reset app preferences'.
3. Then go to Security settings -> Device administrators, and deactivate the device administrator.