# Apps not appearing in Device Administrators

Tags: 7.0-nougat, adoptable-storage, device-administrator, lineageos, 7.1-nougat

I'm running <kbd>Nougat 7.1</kbd> on device and I've came across a strange issue.

Newly installed applications are not listed in the `device administrators` page in security. The list just *doesn't* show newly installed apps, they used to appear on Marshmallow, but the Nougat update broke it. This means that I can't enable *any* newly installed apps as device administrators.

Some apps show the popup to enable them as 'device administrators', but clicking on <kbd>Activate</kbd> does nothing

**'Greenify' should be in the second list, but it isn't:**

[image] [image]

**Things I've attempted (That failed to fix the problem):**

- Clearing Dalvik cache and reinstalling apps
- Booting into safe-mode
- Performing a factory reset

## Question:

The device administrators are stored in a list at `/data/system/device_policies.xml`.
 **Is there any other configuration files relating to the entries of the Device administrators that could prevent new entries from being listed?**

Comment: And what happens if you try adding them manually? Will they appear in the list?

Comment: @xavier_fakerat They still don't appear in the list, even if I add them to `device_policies`. I've also tried deleting that file, and resetting the permissions

Comment: Has any on the solutions decribed here: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/45601/209414 work for you?

Comment: Ok I am still looking for possible resolutions, will let you know if I come up with something interesting.

Comment: @xavier_fakerat I've found this issue, turns out it's a bug with *Adoptable Storage*

Comment: I am glad you managed to resolve the issue, so I will upvote because it will help others with similar issues in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After thoroughly debugging this issue, I've found the cause. It seems to be a *bug* with how **Adoptable Storage** is implemented on my ROM. Any apps that are stored on external storage *are not* shown in the Device Administrators screen.

When using Titanium Backup, I came across the *same issue* as newly installed applications were not visible.

As Android automatically manages storage, it installed **all new apps on the External Storage** which led to this issue. Applications marked as device administrators *are forced* onto the internal storage, meaning any updates they receive won't move them onto the internal storage

**How to fix:**

1. Open up `Apps` in Settings and navigate to the problematic application
2. Click on `Storage` and select <kbd>Change</kbd>
3. Select <kbd>Internal Shared Storage</kbd> and then confirm by pressing <kbd>Move</kbd>