# Is there any command to launch directory of file manager in android phone using adb?

Tags: adb, terminal

I want to open Download folder in my android phone using adb. I have example command for different terminal:`start . /path/to/that/folder` command for command-prompt and `nautilus /path/to/that/folder` for ubuntu terminal. Please help me to find the `adb shell` command..

Comment: See https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/45070/starting-an-activity-listed-under-settings-from-terminal-or-adb-shell . It is a good start.

Comment: It depends on what intents the apps installed on your device can handle. `am start -a android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT -d /sdcard/Download -t '*/*'` works with many file explorer apps.

Comment: @IrfanLatif , These command only open recent activity file. Please help to find the command for Redmi phones..